# SQL Query into Excel Time Format

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have a SQL Query connection in Excel.  The SQL database has a "timedate" column data type "StartTime".  When I return the data back in Excel 2007, the times show up fine (hh:mm:SS AM/PM).  If I open the excel file in Excel 2010 and refresh the query, my times show up as 12:00 AM.  WHY?  I am trying to get Excel to recognize the time format automatically so I can average the "StartTime".

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,tblTime.DateID,101) AS 'DateID', tblTime.ProductionArea, tblTime.Shift, tblTime.EmpNo, tblTime.WONO, CONVERT(datetime,tblTime.StartTime, 120) AS 'StartTime', 
FROM wrenchtime.dbo.tblEmployee tblEmployee, wrenchtime.dbo.tblTime tblTime
WHERE tblEmployee.EmpNo = tblTime.EmpNo AND ((tblTime.DateID Between ? And ?))
ORDER BY tblTime.DateID
```

Comment: It's like the CONVERT function doesn't work in Excel 2010. I have Googled everything I can think of...